# How to merge elements from multiple lists with same ID in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file with 670,000 + lines need to process.
Each line has the format of:

`uid, a, b, c, d, x, y, x1, y1, t, 0,`

I did some cleanning and transferred each line to a list:

`[uid,(x,y,t)]`

And my question is: How can I merge (x,y,t)tuples in different lists but have the common uid efficiently?

For example:
I have multiple lists

```
[uid1,(x1,y1,t1)]
[uid1,(x2,y2,t2)]
[uid2,(x3,y3,t3)]
[uid3,(x4,y4,t4)]
[uid2,(x5,y5,t5)]
......
```

And I want to transfer them into:

```
[uid1,(x1,y1,t1), (x2,y2,z2)]
[uid2,(x3,y3,t3), (x5,52,z5)]
[uid3,(x4,y4,t4)]
......
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the code which you have tried to solve your issue? Please read the following rules to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `defaultdict`.

```
import collections

def group_items(items):
    grouped_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for item in items:
        uid = item[0]
        t = item[1]
        grouped_dict[uid].append(t)

    grouped_list = []
    for uid, tuples in grouped_dict.iteritems():
        grouped_list.append([uid] + tuples)

    return grouped_list
```

`items` is a list of your initial lists.
`grouped_list` will be a list of the grouped lists by uid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `groupby` method from `itertools`. Considering you have your original lists in a variable called `lists`:

```
from itertools import groupby

lists = sorted(lists) # Necessary step to use groupby
grouped_list = groupby(lists, lambda x: x[0])
grouped_list = [(x[0], [k[1] for k in list(x[1])]) for x in grouped_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is stored in a dataframe, you can use `.groupby` to group by the 'uid', and if you transform the values (x,t,v) to a tuple `((x,t,v),)`, you can `.sum` them (i.e. concatenate them).

Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [['a',(1,2,3)],
    ['b',(1,2,3)],
    ['a',(10,9,8)]], columns = ['uid', 'foo']
)

df.apply({'uid': lambda x: x, 'foo': lambda x: (x,)}).groupby('uid').sum()
```

On my end, it produced:

```
uid foo
a   ((1, 2, 3), (10, 9, 8))
b   ((1, 2, 3),)
```

Comment: As a side note - please note that my solution example included a (minimal) data example that allows to demonstrate the problem and the desired result. It should've been added in the question, especially in a Python pandas question. To learn more, please visit the tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour), how to ask (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to ask a pandas question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

How about using defaultdict, like this:

```
L = [['uid1',(x1,y1,t1)],
        ['uid1',(x2,y2,t2)],
        ['uid2',(x3,y3,t3)],
        ['uid3',(x4,y4,t4)],
        ['uid2',(x5,y5,t5)]]


from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

for i in L:
    dd[i[0]].append(i[1])
```

**The output:** print(dd)

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'uid1': [(x1, y1, t1), (x2, y2, t2)],
             'uid2': [(x3, y3, t3), (x5, y5, t5)],
             'uid3': [(x4, y4, t4)]})
```